# update VM time periodically

Tags: linux, date, time, virtual-machine

I have a linux (debian) VM and I need it to run with he UTC time, but for some reason the clock gets out of time in a matter of days.

I don't know if the VM clock runs slower, faster, or gets updated at a certain moment.

It is a VM on a VMware server of virtual machines. I access the VM remotely. And I don't have access to the server.

I tried using ntpd and similar, but the hour ends up changed at the next day.

I only need a 5 minutes precision. UTC time +/- 5 minutes

So I wanted to know if I can make some sort of script that gets executed every hour that updates the date of the VM to the UTC time.

Comment: ntpd works for hundreds of millions pf VMs around the world. Something else is going on with your VM (that would likely also be a problem if you try to periodically execute a script to correct the time) that we cannot debug for you .

Answer (score 0):

1- Install ntp or openntpd - (I use ntp)

2- edit /etc/ntp.conf and be sure there is at least one server

3- start the service ntpd and config to run every time you turn on the PC with:

systemctl enable ntpd
systemctl start ntpd
systemctl status ntpd

Last line is to be sure that the service is running

4- run **timedatectl** and check if the timezone and the autoadjust by ntp is true. You can run **timedatectl --set-ntp 1** to activate it. the time now is update frecuently.

5- check man timedatectl to see other options like UTC time clock and timezone.

Answer (score 0):

//install ntpdate if you dont have it

```
sudo apt-get install ntpdate
```

//update the clock

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```